# Rename multiple files add a suffix

Tags: batch-file, cmd, rename, batch-rename

These are my original file names:

```
C003.png
C004.png
C005.png
C006.png
...
```

I would like my script to modify the name of the file by adding a suffix `-1` as well as keep the original file name at the first:

```
C003-1.png
C004-1.png
C005-1.png
C006-1.png
...
```

How would I go about this on Batch Script?

Comment: `ren ????.png ????-1.*`

Comment: `ren *.png *-1.png`

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to do:

```
ren *.png ???-1.*
```

Answer (score 1):

Open the CMD (<kbd>Window</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, type `cmd` and press enter).

Change the directory to your folder and enter the following command.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('dir /b') do ren "%a" "%%~na-1%%~xa"
```

and press enter, it will rename all the files in the selected folder.